# Prove that in every graph with at least two vertices, there are at least two vertices which have the same degree?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I've tried deriving a proof for this using the handshaking lemma, but that was unsuccessful. Could someone please explain to me how they would do this proof?

Comment: Note that in order for the statement to be true, there also needs to be no self-loops. If there _were_ self loops, then the statement would not be true for a 2-node graph with one of the nodes having a self-loop.

Answer (score 15):

The possible degrees in a graph with $n$ vertices are $0,1,2, \dots, n-1$. Note that no graph with $n$ vertices can contain both a vertex of degree $0$ and a vertex of degree $n-1$, so in each case there are only $n-1$ possible degrees for $n$ vertices.