# A Chess Tournament : All Time Same Number of Game Player

Tags: combinatorial-proofs

Let a Chess Tournament has $n$ participants. And any two players play one game against each other. Then in any point of time, there are two players who have finished the same number of games.

Is it true? If so, what kind of reasoning could be used to prove?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that in every graph with at least two vertices, there are at least two vertices which have the same degree?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523039/prove-that-in-every-graph-with-at-least-two-vertices-there-are-at-least-two-ver)

Comment: To clarify:  your problem is the same as the graph problem as can be seen by considering the graph where the nodes are the players and an edge exists between two players if they have played a game.

Comment: I can see the nodes can be linked to each other.. but how this fact can prove that I can surely find two people who has same number of edges?

Comment: The proof can be found in the link to the duplicate question.

Comment: What does degree refer to in the given link?

Comment: Degree (or valence) in graph theory denotes the number of edges a given node is an endpoint for.  In your case, the degree of a player (node) is the number of games (edges) that the player has played.

Comment: The proof here is nearly trivial:  note that at any given moment a player can have played in one of $\{0,\cdots, n-1\}$ games.  It is not possible that one player has played $0$ while another has played $n-1$ thus in reality at most $n-1$ of those values might actually be the number of games a player has played.  Thus you have $n$ values chosen from $n-1$ so there has to be a duplicate.